# How can i send a MySQL query from Android to add data in database?

Tags: android, mysql

The web is full of content for connecting MySQL within your 'own' android app, BUT BEING NOT A APP DEVELOPER, I DON'T OWN ANY APP.

I want to add data inside MySql database through an Android phone, I can use any android app that can do so. I don't want to access any data but only write it.

Reason- I've got a website currently being operated by CPanel. I need to fetch new data all the time, reason searching a handy Android app and finding ways. Maybe android app of Cpanel can work, idk.

What've I researched- It's possible on desktop: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/setting-up-a-remote-mysql-connection-in-cpanel

Comment: check this link https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: @akhilesh0707 your suggested page says: 'We are going see how to make a very simple Android app (in our case, a product inventory app) that will call a PHP script to perform Create operations.' I'M NOT DEVELOPING AN APP!